# How to specify columns to be merged using pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to use pd.merge , I don't understand how to specify the column we want to add in an other dataframe.

Is it possible?

Below is what I would Like to do :

**DF1**

| index | ID | Style |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a |
| 1 | 21 | z |
| 2 | 7 | e |

**DF2**

| index | ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | ART | 09-13-2022 |
| 1 | 21 | DRAW | 09-13-2022 |
| 1.1 | 7 | GAME | 09-13-2022 |
| ... | 5 | GAME | 09-13-2022 |
| 115 | 8 | GAME | 09-13-2022 |

The output would be :

| index | ID | Style | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a | ART |
| 1 | 21 | z | DRAW |
| 2 | 7 | e | GAME |

I have tried :

```
Output = DF1.merge(DF2, on = 'ID', how='left')
```

Which works but it merge all column and not only the name column.

How can I specify **1 or several** column(s) using `merge`? In this example, we need to specify that we want only Name column to be added to DF1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slice DF2 to only keep the key(s) and the column(s) to add:

```
Output = DF1.merge(DF2[['ID', 'Name']], on='ID', how='left')
```

output:

```
    index   ID  Name
0       0    1   ART
1       1   21  DRAW
2       2    7  GAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the columns associated to your dataframes within the merge itself, for example

```
Output = DF1.merge(DF2[['ID','Name']], on = 'ID', how='left')
```

This will only take the two columns you want into the merge and because 'Name' is an additional column it will join this onto DF1